# Unable to delete project in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to delete project from Google Cloud Platform but not able to do it.

Here you can see what the problem I'm facing.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAp0c.jpg)

**Update**

I got this logs when I try to delete using `gcloud`

`ERROR: (gcloud.projects.delete) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Project [19823334588] has active child resources. You must delete child resources before deleting the project.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - description: Active child resource [services/362464855041] is blocking project
      deletion.
    subject: services/362464855041
    type: CHILD
  - description: Active child resource [services/405735437660] is blocking project
      deletion.
    subject: services/405735437660
    type: CHILD
  - description: Active child resource [services/689680261786] is blocking project
      deletion.
    subject: services/689680261786
    type: CHILD
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help
  links:
  - description: Troubleshooting project deletion
    url: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/troubleshooting-project-deletion
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo
  resourceName: projects/19823334588
  resourceType: PROJECT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest trying to delete the project using [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/delete), sometimes a child resource is needed to be deleted prior and by using gcloud you may get an error with additional information on how to continue with the delete

Comment: Please check the update. How can I delete it

Comment: Do you have [endpoints instances](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/troubleshooting-project-deletion#cloud_endpoints) in your project? If so try delete them first